# Compare node value from xml with String in Python

Tags: python, xml, comparison

After searching a lot and trying a lot I am not able to compare the node from xml with string entered from User in python script.
I hope it is due to a type mismatch because I am getting value from XML in unicode format, 
please suggest the way ASAP to compare two strings successfully.
Thanks in Advance.

My Python script:

```
from  xml.dom.minidom import *
def codin(code):
        document = 'fourth.xml'
        xmldoc = parse(document)
        itemlist = xmldoc.getElementsByTagName('item')
        kool =  itemlist[0].attributes['name'].value
        print kool
        if code ==  kool:
                print type(kool)
                print type(code)
                print "found"
        else:
                print "not found"


        for s in itemlist :
                if code in s.attributes['name'].value:
                        print "Country code matched "
                        country = s.firstChild.nodeValue
                        print country
                        print type(country)
                else:
                        print "not found"

codin('001')
```

XML data:

```
<data>
    <items>
        <item name="001">India</item>
        <item name="002">China</item>
        <item name="003">Spain</item>
        <item name="004">Pakistan</item>
    </items>
</data>
```

Comment: can you add your code, example of XML file and error message to the question?

Comment: you can see code here I have pasted it on pastebin http://pastebin.com/bZdwJPYj

Comment: Prints "Country code matched, India, <type 'unicode'>". What exactly is your problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not clear what you are expecting. Following code reads value from xml file and store it as dictionary so that, you can do your comparison in dictionary.

```
from  xml.dom.minidom import *
def codin(code):
    document = 'fourth.xml'
    xmldoc = parse(document)
    items = xmldoc.getElementsByTagName('items')
    kool = ""
    countryKool = {}
    for n in items:
        rv = getChild(n,'item')
        for v in rv:
            country = v.childNodes[0].nodeValue
            attr = v.getAttributeNode('name')
            if attr:
                kool = attr.nodeValue.strip()
                print "One of item is " , country, " and attribute is ",kool
                countryKool[kool] = country

    if code in countryKool:
        print "found"
    else:
        print "not found"

    print "Mapping of Country and kool ", countryKool #contains mapping for country and kool


def getChild(n,v):
    for child in n.childNodes:
        if child.localName==v:
            yield child

codin('001')
```

Output:

```
One of item is  India  and attribute is  001
One of item is  China  and attribute is  002
One of item is  Spain  and attribute is  003
One of item is  Pakistan  and attribute is  004
found
Mapping of Country and kool  {u'003': u'Spain', u'002': u'China', u'001': u'India', u'004': u'Pakistan'}
```

Answer (score 0):

I resolved the issue, I just had to strip the string and parse it :)